# SQLITE3 step() returns SQLITE_DONE on table with only one row

Tags: select, sqlite

I'am performing an SELECT statment on a sqlite3 database. When the result should be the first row in the table, the return value is always SQLITE_DONE instead of SQLITE_ROW, and I can't get the result.

```
do  {
ret.error = sqlite3_step(stmt);
debug("error: %d",ret.error);
if(ret.error == SQLITE_ROW)
{
  [...]
} } while(ret.error != SQLITE_ERROR && ret.error != SQLITE_DONE && 
ret.error != SQLITE_MISUSE);
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? (The query is correct...)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the code inside the inner "if" statement (`if(ret.error == SQLITE_ROW)`) is never reached? If your `stmt` is valid, the final value of `ret.error` will always be SQLITE_DONE. Suggestion: what's the SQL statement (`stmt`), how are you preparing it, and what's the row in your database that you're trying to retrieve?

Comment: I just rewrote the code, now it seems to work, not sure what the error was

Answer (score 0):

Switching from "Debug" configuration to "Release" resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

after the **While Loop**.